# WPF Custom Attached Property in DataTrigger

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, attached-properties

I've looked at similar questions here on SO and wasn't able to get a solution, so here's my deal:

** I Have the following class: **

```
public static class ControlSecurity
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSecuredProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsSecured",
            typeof (bool),
            typeof (FrameworkElement),
            new PropertyMetadata(false));

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(Control))]
    public static bool GetIsSecured(FrameworkElement ctl)
    {
        return (bool)ctl.GetValue(IsSecuredProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsSecured(FrameworkElement ctl, bool value)
    {
        ctl.SetValue(IsSecuredProperty, value);
    }
}
```

As you can surmise, it adds `Security:ControlSecurity.IsSecured` to all `FrameworkElement`s.

*Note: `Security:` Points to the namespace all these classes are in (including `ControlSecurity`)*

So I've implemented this data-template & style for one of my controls:

```
       <DataTemplate x:Key="SecureButtonTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="SecureIcon" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Icons/secure.png" Width="16" Height="16" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=Security:ControlSecurity.IsSecured}" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="SecureIcon" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SecureButtonTemplate}" />
        </Style>
```

The problem here lies in the binding on the `DataTrigger`:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=Security:ControlSecurity.IsSecured}
```

The idea is, I want to find the parent button, and bind to it's `Security:ControlSecurity.IsSecured` attached property I've defined.

I've tried about 10 different variations on this binding, and I keep getting a binding error somewhat like this:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Security:ControlSecurity' property not found on 'object' ''Button' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Security:ControlSecurity.IsSecured; DataItem='Button' (Name=''); target element is 'ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

I'm stumped at this point, and would love some insight from the WPF gurus out there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add parenthesis :

```
Path=(Security:ControlSecurity.IsSecured)
```

Comment: Alright, I did that, now I get a XAML Parse Exception with an inner exception stating:

Property path is not valid. 'ControlSecurity' does not have a public property named 'IsSecured'.

Comment: Disregard my above comment I figured that one out, Had the wrong owner defined in my attached property.

Comment: Sweet something religious, that was doing my head in. Thanks