# Blur The Background Of A Custom Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

The title might not be clear but I will explain now. I have a custom control that represents a modal (inspired by SingltonSean), When I trigger a command, it shows this modal that covers the rest of the elements behind it, it somewhat acts like a popup. Now I want everything behind it to be blurred. How can I achieve that?

This is my modal custom control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type viewModel:Modal}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type viewModel:Modal}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid Visibility="{TemplateBinding IsOpen, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.025" />
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True"  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Grid.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=border}" />
                            </Grid.OpacityMask>
                            <Border x:Name="border" Background="White" CornerRadius="20" />
                            <Grid Width="500" Height="600">
                                <StackPanel Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Button Padding="10 5" Content="Close Modal" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blur the background of the WPF container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815278/blur-the-background-of-the-wpf-container)

Comment: It does not, because I am not using an image as a background. @Sinatr

Comment: Have you read all answers? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7817182/1997232) should do: the container behind should be blurred.

Comment: Sorry, it is not working either. Have you tried that solution on my code?

Comment: No, but I am using blurr effect myself, similarly to that answer. What's not working? What you tried, what happend and what you want instead?

Comment: Under the Grid.Background tag I added this
<Border>
     <Border.Effect>
      <BlurEffect Radius="5" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
     </Border.Effect/>
  </Border>
And it did not blur the background content.

Comment: Is "background content" a part of the control?

Comment: No it is not. This custom control exists on top of other content.

Comment: So why are you trying to add blur inside the control? Add blur to where content is.

Comment: What would be the best approach in your opinion? This custom control is reusable and if I go with your approach it will require me to add blur to the other content of every view every time I use that custom control. I thought maybe I can add a layer inside my custom control that is blurred above that content and then display the modal but it is not working for me.

Comment: See my answer, that's what the second part of it attempts to achieve using attached behavior. You can't encapsulate blur effect inside (afaik), but you can apply it to something outside of your control. There is still work to do: un-blurring and using another approach than `ElementName` to pass instance of container you want to blur, but should be a good starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply blur where content is:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="20"/>
        </Grid.Effect>
        <TextBlock Text="Some content I want to blur"/>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Popup"/>
</Grid>
```

If you want to make a control, which is able to blur something before in visual tree, you still need to apply effect to it. One possibility is to use attached behavior:

```
public static class Behavior
{
    public static UIElement GetBlurTarget(DependencyObject obj) => (UIElement)obj.GetValue(BlurTargetProperty);
    public static void SetBlurTarget(DependencyObject obj, UIElement value) => obj.SetValue(BlurTargetProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BlurTargetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BlurTarget", typeof(UIElement), typeof(Behavior), new PropertyMetadata((d, e) =>
        {
            if (e.NewValue is UIElement element)
                element.Effect = new BlurEffect { Radius = 20 };
        }));
}
```

Then layout should be like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="container">
        <TextBlock Text="Some content I want to blur" />
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Popup" local:Behavior.BlurTarget="{Binding ElementName=container}"/>
</Grid>
```

Both cases will produce same result:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: I have a question, my modal has a boolean dependency property called IsOpen, how can I only blur the BlurTarget UIElement when my IsOpen is true?

Comment: hey, have you seen my last comment?

Comment: You can create another behavior to remove effect and then use data trigger to either set or remove blur (don't forget to [use parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3514416/1997232)) depending on the value of `IsOpen`.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am struggling, it is not working for me. I have declared the BlurTarget as a dependency property, and I added a data trigger in my control template that does this:
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOpen}" Value="False"><Setter Property="BlurTarget"><Setter.Value><UIElement><UIElement.Effect><BlurEffect Radius="0" /></UIElement.Effect></UIElement></Setter.Value></Setter></DataTrigger>

Comment: What do you think about my approach?